tailwindCSS not working in nextJS and Shadcn project
None of the tailwind classnames are working in this project.
I have one of each file like components.json, globals.css, and tailwind.config.ts, and the globals.css is imported in the layout.tsx file however the styling still does not work. I've tried deleting node-modules, and re-running npm install, but no change.
Please help me spot the issue.
File structure:
globals.css is in the app folder, and imported in the layout file(though no auto-complete when entering the import)

globals.css:
tailwind imports

Tailwind.config.ts:
Content paths all included.

components.json:
tailwind config and globals files included.

Package.json:

